# Using CoffeeScript singleton classes to abstract jQuery events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, singleton, jquery-events

**Update: 2016-02-12 16:00**

So this is what I'm thinking at the moment:

```
$(document).on "ready", ->
  window.Layout.setup()

# Utilizes class variables and methods
class window.Layout
  @setup: () ->
    @initializeVariables()
    @setEvents()

  @initializeVariables: () ->
    @overlay = $("#overlay")

  @setEvents: () ->
    @overlay.on "click", ->
      alert "clicked..."

  @showOverlay: () ->
    @overlay.addClass("visible")

  @hideOverlay: () ->
    @overlay.removeClass("visible")
```

This allows me to encapsulate some of the logic into classes using class variables and methods.  I don't necessarily need instantiated objects, since there will usually only be 1 class I need to work with (there's only 1 logical "layout" in an application).

It just seems very repetitive to use `@` everywhere to achieve this...

**Original Question**

In short, I'm building a Rails 4+ web application and I'm using jQuery with CoffeeScript to manipulate DOM events (show/hide elements, animations, etc...).

I have an overlay/mask that covers the main window and a left sidebar that can be toggled to show on top of the overlay, similar to how any Android Material Design app works with the drawer component.

I can throw all my event handlers into a single file (or break them into separate files but same issue IMO) like this and it works:

```
# js.coffee file
$(document).on "ready", ->
  $("#left-sidebar-toggle").on "click", ->
    if $(this).hasClass("visible")
      $(this).removeClass("visible")
      $("#overlay").removeClass("visible")
    else
      $("#overlay").addClass("visible")
      $("#left-sidebar").addClass("visible")

  $("#overlay").on "click", ->
    $("#left-sidebar").removeClass("visible")
    $(this).removeClass("visible")

  # ...many more various event handlers...
```

However, when you have a bunch of event handlers (because I want a rich experience for my users), this becomes a monolithic file with everything just throw into one place.  Even if I split it into multiple files, I still have it all really thrown into the global space with a lot of duplicate code.

My thought was abstracting the logic into CoffeeScript singleton classes that handle this:

```
# Namespace
window.App ||= {}

class App.Layout
  @showOverlay: () ->
    $("#overlay").addClass("visible")

  @hideOverlay: () ->
    $("#overlay").removeClass("visible")

  @setEvents: () ->
    # Define here because DOM not loaded when class is created
    @overlay = $("#overlay")
    @leftSidebarToggle = $("#left-sidebar-toggle")

    $(document).on "click", App.Layout.leftSidebarToggle, ->
      # ...

    $(document).on "click", App.Layout.overlay, ->
      # ...

$(document).on("ready"), ->
  App.Layout.setEvents()
```

However, as I was flushing out these classes, it doesn't seem to be much better.

Is there some standard for how one interacts with the DOM using a CoffeeScript class like this?  I'm trying to implement an object-oriented solution that's maintainable, and neither of these 2 solutions seem viable at the moment.

Comment: Just use a simple object literal. Do not use `class` syntax when you don't want to instantiate anything.